# Create Calendar Control in Windows Phone 8

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

How can I use Microsoft Templates to create Calendar Control ? 
Can someone provide me a code for this ? or which references should I have to create a calendar.
And one more question, how references are used ?
I`m a beginner, so excuse me :)
Regards.

Answer (score 4):

You can try free controls at http://phone.codeplex.com/. This includes DateTimePicker control, which may fulfill your requirements. There are also samples provided with it. There is also a special Calendar control. Check it out here: http://wpcontrols.codeplex.com/

Hope, this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can see in Telerik libraries that contain calender controluse this.